# Rails Simple Form Wrapper for Bootstrap Switch?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

Does anyone know how to write a [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form%20wrapper) wrapper for [bootstrap-switch](http://www.larentis.eu/switch/)?

The resulting HTML needs to look like this:

```
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want using wrapper bootstrap-switch and resulting html. I see no difference between [form-horizontal original bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#form-horizontal) and [form-horizontal bootstrap switch](http://www.larentis.eu/switch/#form-horizontal)

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you would use the bootstrap switch script for a textfield. Nonetheless, some people might end up here with the same question as the one asked in the title.

You can simply copy the bootstrap wrapper and add the required class:

```
config.wrappers :bootstrap_switch, tag: 'div', class: "control-group", error_class: 'error', boolean_style: :inline do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper tag: 'div', class: 'controls' do |ba|
    ba.wrapper "switch", tag: 'div', class: 'switch' do |s|
      s.use :input
    end
    ba.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
    ba.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block' }
  end
end
```

This will create a nested div that has the class 'switch' (and thus stylable by the script). This inner wrapper has the namespace "switch", which enables us to set some options:

```
f.input :inputField, :wrapper => :bootstrap_switch, :switch_html => { :data => { on: "success", on_label: "<i class='icon-ok icon-white'></i>", off: "warning", off_label: "<i class='icon-remove'></i>" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Form [example application has it](http://simple-form-bootstrap.plataformatec.com.br/examples/custom) now with the following [code](https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap/blob/4e1edacc809d447205c896173183d915381ce46b/config/initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb#L288).

```rb
  # custom input switch for boolean
  config.wrappers :custom_boolean_switch, tag: 'fieldset', class: 'form-group', error_class: 'form-group-invalid', valid_class: 'form-group-valid' do |b|
    b.use :html5
    b.optional :readonly
    b.wrapper :form_check_wrapper, tag: 'div', class: 'custom-control custom-switch' do |bb|
      bb.use :input, class: 'custom-control-input', error_class: 'is-invalid', valid_class: 'is-valid'
      bb.use :label, class: 'custom-control-label'
      bb.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: 'div', class: 'invalid-feedback' }
      bb.use :hint, wrap_with: { tag: 'small', class: 'form-text text-muted' }
    end
  end
```

and the usage is

```
<%= f.input :terms, wrapper: :custom_boolean_switch %>
```

Answer (score -3):

simple_form has a bootstrap plugin built in. Check it out [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#twitter-bootstrap).

Comment: Yes, I am using that, but I need a wrapper for bootstrap-switch.